# Does rolling all 6's on an attack roll with a Failure Prone weapon result in an Upgraded Success or does the weapon explode?

Tags: critical-hit, planet-mercenary

Normally, rolling all 6's on a skill check results in an Upgraded Success if your total is high enough to hit, doubling damage. However, weapons with the Failure Prone quality will explode on triples.

> Any roll of triples when attacking with this weapon causes the weapon to explode
>   instead of firing. The explosion inflicts the weapon’s normal damage on you and
>   anyone next to you (as determined by the combat conditions and the GC).
>   The weapon is destroyed in the process and may not be repaired.

Which effect takes precedence for rolling all 6's?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are at least two interpretations you can take with this.

1.) The weapon explodes, dealing double damage to you and those around you. (this is my preferred.)

2.) The Failure of the weapon prevents an Upgraded success from happening, and the Weapon explodes normally.

It is deliberately left vague in the game because this particular scenario makes the Game Chief have to choose the most narratively entertaining option. That means while, I support the two options above, they are not the only right answers.

**Relevant Bits:** I wrote the rules for the RPG.

Comment: ^_^ Someone on Facebook also suggested that both might happen, the explosion damaging your target as well as yourself and everyone around you as it cooks off.

Comment: That's cuz we're all smart folks!